# What is the pun that is intended in this sentence?

Tags: pun

I read this in Word by Word by Kory Stamper:

> Teachers will write in and angrily ask how they can possibly teach their students proper grammar and punctuation if *the dictionary* can be bothered to use it? Even that is changing, however there is room online to put in both the subject *and* terminal punctuation, thereby (we hope) saving students of English from utter inevitable idiocy.

I want to ask why has the author written "and" in italics? Of course, there must be a subtle pun but I don't get what exactly it is.

Comment: The author used italics for emphasis.

Comment: @Kreiri Is right. In other words: there is no pun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was already noticed that emphasis is the purpose, but the object of emphasis was forgotten in the explanations :)

The author wants to say this:

- only one problem is already bad;
- but two problems are a lot worse: "subject AND terminal punctuation".

In spoken language, we would pronounce "and" in a louder voice, just to underline that there is more than one problem.

Answer (score 0):

I mean I'm no expert, but it seems as though the "and" was italicized just to emphasize the annoyed tone of whoever is speaking. It doesn't necessarily have to be a pun. But, in case it is, I think what would help you is finding what "terminal punctuation" is. Maybe it's a technical term in English grammar or something.

If you doubt that it has been italicised to signify annoyance or an annoyed tone, I urge you to read a novel or browse through any comment section. This [website](https://www.ignitedinkwriting.com/ignite-your-ink-blog-for-writers/using-italics/2017) I just found, for example, talks about it. I even remember seeing it in some news articles and some product reviews.

anyway, good luck.